# How do I switch layout with Ctrl+Shift or Alt+Shift in LXDE?

Tags: keyboard-layout, lxde

How do I switch layout with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> or such in LXDE?

All else being equal, I would prefer:

- a command-line solution
- a desktop environment-independent solution

so that I can automate my next installation of Ubuntu to include it by default, and so that the recipe still works if I will be actually using another desktop environment in the future.

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 32-bit with LXDE installed. I would like to be able to cycle through English and Russian layouts with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> (as I already do in Unity).

Currently, when I go to "Preferences" --> "Keyboard Input Methods" I see the following (note that I have only managed to add <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> as a shortcut to switch layouts, which is not what I wanted):

[image]

Then, when I click the ellipsis (note the line `Control z` that you can see via a tiny crack of a window under "Keyboard shortcuts"):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/keyboard
```

(or use some other text editor)

Do following changes in the file:

```
XKBLAYOUT="ru,us"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS="grp:ctrl_shift_toggle"
```

Restart and try again.

But the problem is that every desktop environment has his method to override this default settings, the methods are all different. In Lubuntu (14.04) as example the file `$HOME/.config/lxpanel/Lubuntu/panels` contains the settings for the layout plugin and it must be set to `KeepSysLayouts=1`, so the default settings are not overridden.

Comment: I wonder if maybe I could just rely on X keyboard layout switching if I won't enable desktop environment's mechanisms? (which are supposedly off by default, as there is no keyboard layout indicator by default). I guess I have to try this out on a fresh install or a virtual machine, to be sure.